# How do I record user input during install, so it can be used during uninstall?

Tags: inno-setup

During setup I record input from the user such as the name of the Windows service that is being created. When uninstalling this service I need to know what was originally entered as service name by the user.

What is the best way to get the service name during uninstall?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The best fitting to your requirement seems to be to handle the [`RegisterPreviousData`](http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=scriptevents&anchor=RegisterPreviousData) event method and from inside it call the [`SetPreviousData`](http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=isxfunc_setpreviousdata) function, in which you can store a string value under your custom key. To restore the previously stored data you can call [`GetPreviousData`](http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=isxfunc_getpreviousdata) function.

Here is a simple example of the usage:

```pascal
[Code]
var
  UserPage: TInputQueryWizardPage;

procedure InitializeWizard;
begin
  UserPage := CreateInputQueryPage(wpWelcome, 'Caption', 'Description', '');
  UserPage.Add('Service name:', False);
end;

procedure RegisterPreviousData(PreviousDataKey: Integer);
begin
  SetPreviousData(PreviousDataKey, 'ServiceName', UserPage.Values[0]);
end;

function InitializeUninstall: Boolean;
var
  ServiceName: string;
begin
  ServiceName := GetPreviousData('ServiceName', '');
  if ServiceName <> '' then
    MsgBox('The value entered before: ' + ServiceName, mbInformation, MB_OK);
end;
```