# Restore previously entered data on custom page next time Inno Setup-made installer is executed

Tags: inno-setup, pascalscript

I want to use this code, but the part of the code to uninstall I need: in the next time I open the executable it can read the information written in this field 'Service name'.

Can help me?

And even now where it stores this information written in the 'Service name'?

Related to:
[How do I record user input during install, so it can be used during uninstall?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19776423)

Comment: Related to [your previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/25183287/588306).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you're looking for a way to fill an input field with the previously stored data. In the example that you linked you can notice that there is used the [`GetPreviousData`](http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=isxfunc_getpreviousdata) function which is used just for reading data previously stored by the [`SetPreviousData`](http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=isxfunc_setpreviousdata) function call.

The principle is, that when the [`RegisterPreviousData`](http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=scriptevents&anchor=RegisterPreviousData) event fires, you call the [`SetPreviousData`](http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=isxfunc_setpreviousdata) function for each value that you want to store, providing for each value some unique key (parameter of this function is called `ValueName` which is not much self-explaining). For example here is how to store values from two different input fields:

```pascal
procedure RegisterPreviousData(PreviousDataKey: Integer);
begin
  SetPreviousData(PreviousDataKey, 'MyUniqueKey1', InputPage.Values[0]);
  SetPreviousData(PreviousDataKey, 'MyUniqueKey2', InputPage.Values[1]);
end;
```

As I already mentioned, data stored this way you can read by using [`GetPreviousData`](http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=isxfunc_getpreviousdata) function which you can call right after you add your input fields. Into this function you'll pass the same key as you used to store the data and except that you'll pass also the default value, which will be returned when the data for the given key won't be found. For the above code example it can be like this:

```pascal
procedure InitializeWizard;
var
  Index: Integer;
begin
  InputPage := CreateInputQueryPage(wpWelcome, 'Caption', 'Description', '');

  Index := InputPage.Add('Input field 1:', False);
  InputPage.Values[Index] := GetPreviousData('MyUniqueKey1', 'Default value');

  Index := InputPage.Add('Input field 2:', False);
  InputPage.Values[Index] := GetPreviousData('MyUniqueKey2', 'Default value');
end;
```

This mechanism uses registry as a storage for values. To be more specific, it is the same key as where the uninstallation information are stored. Actually, what is passed by `PreviousDataKey` parameter of the [`RegisterPreviousData`](http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=scriptevents&anchor=RegisterPreviousData) event method is a handle to the just created uninstallation data registry key, which is used to tell the [`SetPreviousData`](http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=isxfunc_setpreviousdata) function where to store the data.

Value keys in that registry key path are composed from the fixed `Inno Setup CodeFile:` prefix part followed by the unique key passed in the [`SetPreviousData`](http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=isxfunc_setpreviousdata) function. So, for our example would Inno Setup create the following value keys in uninstallation data registry key path:

```pascal
Inno Setup CodeFile: MyUniqueKey1
Inno Setup CodeFile: MyUniqueKey2
```

Comment: Thank you, TLana. I will now join the code of my installer.